# Have to create and return objects from classes that implement interfaces java

Tags: java, interface, singleton

I have a to create a new library object and return it in Test. But since ILibrary is an Interface I cant instantiate ILibrary.
How do I create a class that implements the Ilibrary and that gives me an object I can return?

```
public class Test extends Iface {

    @Override
    public ILibrary createLibrary() {
        //TODO: Instantiate library
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

the Interface is

```
public interface Iface {
    public ILibrary createLibrary()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class should implement Iface not extends it and you can't instantiate a interface because interface are abstract. Your class Test can be :

```java
public class Test implements Iface{


}
```